# how to find accessoryType click in tableview in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

i need to do something on `accessoryType` click in tableview in iphone.how can i find `accessoryType` click in `UITableView` in iphone.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use this delegate method for this purpose

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

This fires when you click on accessory

Comment: You use this method with DetailDisclosureButton when you need two different action one on selection of the row and one with tapping on accessory.

Answer (score 9):

you need to define the `accessoryType` of the cell in the

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

like this

```
cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton;
```

the method for row selection of this accessoryType is

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

but if you are defining any other accessoryType for cell than you can use this method.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```